# How do I delete VALID_ARCHS?

Tags: ios, xcode12, xcode12.5

My development environment is: *macOS 11.3.1*, *Xcode 12.5.1*, *CocoaPods 1.9.3*

My problem is that in my project's **TAEGETS**, it shows the field `VALID_ARCHS` and I can't delete it. But it is not there in **PROJECT**.

I can't find the field in the corresponding `project.pbxproj` either, so now I don't know how to remove it.

When I create a new project and the field is not in **TAEGETS** or **PROJECT**, I can create a new project and move all my files over. But I **don't** want to take this approach if I don't have to.

Is there any other way to solve my problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out why: it was introduced through some pod.

I created a new project and reintroduced my pods one by one until I couldn't compile the project in the emulator, and eventually I found the faulty pod.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you see that because you have edited it in the past and are looking at "Basic".  You can just set it to the same as the default and you'll be fine but if you want it to behave like the other projects and be default, you can edit project.pbxproj and just delete all the lines for `VALID_ARCHS` then make sure you're looking at "Basic" as it is always shown under "All"

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but in other projects, whether I check the "Basic" or "All", there is no `VALID_ARCHS` field. Since I joined the project halfway through, I have no way of knowing if anyone has edited it in the past. The killer thing is that I can't find anything about `VALID_ARCHS` in `project.pbxproj`, but it does show up in my Xcode...

Comment: There must be other differences then, are you making the project for the same target?  Like is it for macOS with the same SDK and deployment version?